# Timeout when using AWS CLI without internet (with endpoint)

Tags: connection, amazon-web-services

I m trying to use AWS CLI on a AWS VM on a VPC without internet connectivity. I created an endpoint on the VPC for the AWS EC2 service and using debug log it seems it is used but I end up with a timeout.... I wonder what I could try to debug what is happening.

Here is my AWS command:

> aws ec2 describe-instances --debug --query
>   'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,State.Name,Tags[?Key==`Name`]
>   | [0].Value]' --endpoint-url
>   https://vpce-0be5a2862c4c3a54e-ree2d4dy.execute-api.us-east-2.vpce.amazonaws.com

and the logs before it timeout:

> ..... 2019-04-14 20:41:30,317 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG
>   - Sending http request:  2019-04-14 20:41:30,318 - MainThread -
>   botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - INFO -
>   Starting new HTTPS connection (1):
>   vpce-0be5a2862c4c3a54e-ree2d4dy.execute-api.us-east-2.vpce.amazonaws.com
>   .....

Any advice welcome. Thx

Comment: The endpoint has a security group associated with it, and needs to allow HTTPS from your instance.  Have you configured that?

Comment: my mistake....the SG was open for VM using this security group....which was not the case of the vm where i was ruining the command. I fully open the SG and request go throught now. If you answer that i will accept ;)